# how to display the highlighted html script of a html page rendered through iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to show the source code of a html page that rendered by in an html page as highlighted in IDE.
I fetched the source code of an iframe html file

```
    $('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

this gives me a string and no highlight is applied.

here is all my code to fetch and display iframe file

```
    $('#html').click(function(){
            var sourceCode  = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n\<html lang="en-US">\n';
                sourceCode += $('#html-iframe').contents().find("html").html();
                sourceCode += '\n</html>';
                sourceCode  = sourceCode.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
                sourceCode  = "<pre>"+sourceCode+"</pre>";
            $('#html-div code').append(sourceCode);

        });
```

Comment: All that does is replaces less than (<) and greater than (>) characters with the encoded equivalent. You'll need some CSS to highlight the modified HTML in the "html-div code" element.

Comment: but how i apply css for every tag, their properties and content individually.

Comment: and also var sourceCode return a string is there any way i can get var sourceCode in type of html/javascript object

Comment: Have a look at [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/)